# use spark sql through Scala IDE

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i want to try spark sql , i used at first the bin/spark-shell 
inserting this code

```
val sqlcontext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val data=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/cars.csv")
val mapr=data.map (p => p.split(','))
val MyMatchRDD=mapr.map(p =>MyMatch(p(0).toString(),p(1).toString(),p(2).toString(),
    p(3).toString(),p(4).toString(),p(5).toString(),p(6).toString(),p(7).toString(),
    p(8).toString()))

import sqlcontext.implicits._
val personDF=MyMatchRDD.toDF()
personDF.registerTempTable("Person")
val res = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT * FROM Person")
res.collect().foreach(println)
```

i didn't get any issue ,all is good.
But when i used the scala ide 
i used in pom file (maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and i used the same code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

object SparkSQL {
    case class MyMatch( col1: String, col2: String,col3: String, col4 :String ,col5: String,
       col6: String,col7 :String ,col8: String, 
       col9: String)

    def main(args:Array[String]) { 
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveFromSpark").setMaster("local")
        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
        val sqlcontext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

        val data=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/cars.csv")
        val mapr=data.map (p => p.split(','))
        val MyMatchRDD=mapr.map(p =>MyMatch(p(0).toString(),p(1).toString(),p(2).toString(),p(3).toString(),
             p(4).toString(),p(5).toString(),p(6).toString(),p(7).toString(),
            p(8).toString()) )

        import sqlcontext.implicits._
        val personDF=MyMatchRDD.toDF()
        personDF.registerTempTable("Person")
        val res = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT * FROM Person")
        res.collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

i got this issue

> Exception in thread "main"
>   scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection in JavaMirror with
>   primordial classloader with boot classpath
>   [D:\scala-SDK-4.4.1-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.scala-

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: May I ask how you came to the decision to use Spark version 1.3.0?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an wrong Scala version - Spark's compiled with Scala version 2.10. Check your runtime and compiler Scala version.

Why you're using so old dependencies? Spark has version 2.0.2 right now with Scala 2.11

Recommended actions:

1. (optional) Change `<version>1.3.0</version>` to `<version>2.0.2</version>`
2. In your Scala compiler, change version to 2.11 (if updated to Spark 2) or 2.10 (if you still use Spark 1)
3. Make sure you have proper Scala version installed on your machine - 2.11 in case of Spark 2, 2.10 in case of Spark 1. You can check Scala version by typing `scala -version` in console
4. Make sure your Scala IDE supports Scala version that was choosen

Comment: am new with spark , what should i do please ? thanks in advance

Comment: In your pom.xml your spark version is 1.3.0. You should update this to the latest version. As of right now, it is 2.0.2.

Comment: what about the compiler how do i upgrade to scala 2.11 ?

Comment: Spark 2.0.2 is built and distributed to work with Scala 2.11 so you should just update maven project by right clicking on the project then  `Maven > Update Project`

Comment: @HattabiMaher I've added steps what you must do. Let me know if it's ok for you

Comment: @jabbathehutt1234 Thanks for edit, but error is about wrong Scala version - author may use old Spark, but with old Scala. I've corrected that to show root cause, but thanks for grammar edits :)